# I can't get fetch to work with async/await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await, fetch

I'm starting with Javascript, I am trying to make a fetch behave synchronously. I need that after calling a function that ends up calling the fecth to process the result.

```
async function _send_sync_command(command) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5700" + "/ext", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
  body: JSON.stringify(command)
  });

  const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}

function send_command(command) {
  this._send_sync_command(command)
  .then((data) => {
    return data;
  })
}


function DownloadToFP(star_cmd, next_cmd, end_cmd) {
  var json_out = {};
  json_out.data_0 = "";
  json_out.data_1 = "";
    
  // Start download command
  var response = this.send_command(star_cmd);

  // I need this to run after all promises are resolved !!!

  if (response.fields.length > 0) {
    json_out.data_0 = response.fields[0];
  }
}
```

Comment: You can never make fetch execute synchronously, why not make `DownloadToFP async` and await on `this.send_command`?

Comment: And if you want to update UI eventually somehow then again either await inside an asynchronous function or just use `.then` or even update the UI inside a callback, that's how asynchronous work.

Comment: It is not possible to make an async task run synchronous. For the same reason that you can not open a Package **now** that you'll receive tomorrow. `async/await` allows you to write code that looks *almost* like sync code, but it is not. That's the best we have at the moment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `await` the `_send_sync_command` function to stop the execution of the function at this point, and return back when all promises are resolved.

Also, I don't think you need `send_command` function.

***UPDATE***

as @danh suggests to return `json_out` from `DownloadToFP` function.

```js
async function _send_sync_command(command) {
  const response = await fetch("http://localhost:5700" + "/ext", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
        "Content-type": "application/json; charset=UTF-8"
    },
  body: JSON.stringify(command)
  });

  const data = await response.json();
    return data;
}


async function DownloadToFP(star_cmd, next_cmd, end_cmd) {
  var json_out = {};
  json_out.data_0 = "";
  json_out.data_1 = "";
    
  // Start download command
  var response = await this._send_sync_command(star_cmd);

  // I need this to run after all promises are resolved !!!

  if (response.fields.length > 0) {
    json_out.data_0 = response.fields[0];
  }
  return json_out
}
```